# Single animation on stateless React component

Tags: reactjs, animation, popmotion

I've started working with react-pose and had a question that I had for most animation setups in React.

1. It would seem you can't trigger animation on a component on first render?

Here is why I ask the above questions. Below is a react-pose example trying to use a stateless component. I would expect when I add this to my main.js render like so.  it would

1. first mount FadeDiv component with initialPose set to opacity of 0
2. then set pose="enter" on render which is set to opacity: 1. But that's not
   the case. Now that would be nice and simple if this were the case.

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import posed from 'react-pose';

   const FadeDiv = posed.div({
     enter: { opacity: 1 },
     before: { opacity: 0 },
     initialPose: 'before'
   });

   export const Wrapper = () => (
    <FadeDiv pose="enter">
      <div>This is a fading div</div>
    </FadeDiv>
   );
   ```

Correct me if I'm wrong but this is what I believe is happening. 
When React mounts the stateless or any component it has no idea of initialPose until its fully mounted at this stage its too late and it just sets the component's opacity to the pose="enter" this is why I'm not seeing an animation from 0 - 1 because it mounted with the opacity set to **"enter"** which is opacity 1. So it just appears without any animation.

Ok so if the above is correct then I added this setup below which is extra boilerplate of adding a state, but I guess is necessary for React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import posed from 'react-pose';

const FadeDiv = posed.div({
  enter: { opacity: 1 },
  before: { opacity: 0 },
  initialPose: 'before'
});

class Wrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isEnter: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isEnter: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FadeDiv pose={this.state.isEnter ? 'enter' : 'before'}>
        <div>This is a fading div</div>
      </FadeDiv>
    );
  }
}

export default Wrapper;
```

Now it all works but I have to force a second render for to switch between isEnter which is false on first render ( mount component ) and then set to true when component did mount hook.

Sorry for the long winded explanation but its important for me to full understand. 
Is this extra amount of boilerplate the only solution to have a simple div animate ?  First wrap component with a life cycle hook of componentDidMount to trigger a second render using state. 
I presume what's happening her as a break down for me and possible others to understand is:

1. initial render pose={this.state.isEnter ? 'enter' : 'before'} is set
   to "before" which means the FadeDiv component is opacity 0
2. then second render gets triggered by state change to set
   pose="enter" which sets opacity to 1 and animates the component
   from 0 - 1.

**Would that be a correct assumption ?**

With that in mind is this how people really get around animation in React with extra boilerplate every time you need a simple animation. Yes I understand you could use css but you still need to to wait for the component to mount to set first style to opacity=0 then re-render to set opacity=1.But the question here is about Popmotion's React-pose and I guess React itself and its pitfalls when using animation of DOM elements.

Comment: Is there anyone out there that can confirm my findings if they have worked with react-pose or any animation in React for that matter ??

Comment: You can use [PoseGroup](https://popmotion.io/pose/api/posegroup/) to create enter/exit transitions.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Popmotion/popmotion/issues/361#issuecomment-395037669

You should check this out.

```
<Box
  style={styles}
  initialPose="closed"
  pose="open"
/>
```

With a closed initial pose, `Box` will animate on mounting.

This is a Codesandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/n5y2v17rwl

Answer (score -1):

I have been working with react-spring which, looking at the docs, is very similar to react-pose.

One important thing you are missing is the transition property, that works very well with the opacity property.

Instead of creating a functional component as you did, I handle animations by directly changing the opacity.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state ={
      opacity: 0
    }
  }
 componentDidMount() {
   this.handleTransition()
 }

 handleTransition = () => (
   setTimeout(() => this.setState({opacity: 1}), 400 )
 )

 render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{opacity: this.state.opacity, transition: "opacity 3s ease"}}>
      <h1>Faded Div </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/6v6l7xo4zz

Currently I find setting the opacity in state is one of the only ways to handle transitions. It is not that bad tho, it is only 2-3 lines of extra code.